# Notification Message with big text

Tags: android

I'm building a Service to send some notification at the user also when the smartphone is locked.

I don't have any problem if I try to start my application, I can see this message Notification but I can't read all the text.

This is that I can see:
[image]

As you can see the first message is:

> Attività Insufficiente
>   Svolgi al più presto l'attività fisica Pallavolo! ! Clicca su questa notifica per avviare l'esercizio...

But I can see only:

> Attività Insufficiente
>   Svolgi al più presto l'attività fisica Pallavolo! ! Clicca su..

As you can see the text is cut.

Now thie is the code that I use to send Notification message:

```
void readNotifications(){
        List<NotificationMessage> messages = db.getAllNotificationMessages();

        for (NotificationMessage messageCurr:messages) {
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext());

            if(messageCurr.getTypeId() == NOTIFICATION_GREEN) {
                mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_green);
                mBuilder.setContentTitle("Continua cosi!");
            }
            else {
                mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_red);
                mBuilder.setContentTitle("Attività insufficiente");
            }

            mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageCurr.getMessage()));
            mBuilder.setContentText("Svolgi al più presto l'attività fisica Pallavvolo ! Clicca su questa notifica per avviare l'esercizio..." );

            NotificationAction currAction = db.getNotificationActionById(messageCurr.getActionId());
            if(currAction != null){
                //lego la action
                String[] separated = currAction.getActivityName().split("-");
                boolean isNewActivity = (separated[0].equals(NEW_ACTIVITY_START));
                int idAction = Integer.valueOf(separated[1]);
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), (isNewActivity) ? InsertNewActivity.class : ManageActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                if(isNewActivity)
                    b.putInt(PAR_NOTIFICATION_EXERCISEID, idAction);
                else
                    b.putInt(ActivitiesFragment.PAR_ACTIVITY_ID, idAction);

                resultIntent.putExtras(b);

                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                        PendingIntent.getActivity(
                                getBaseContext(),
                                new Random().nextInt(),
                                resultIntent,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT,
                                b
                        );
                mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

            }

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            // notificationID allows you to update the notification later on.
            mNotificationManager.notify(messageCurr.getId(), mBuilder.build());

            //imposto la notifica come letta
            messageCurr.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
```

This is NotificationAction.java:

```
public class NotificationAction {
    private int id;
    private String activityName;
    private boolean enabled;

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getActivityName() {
        return activityName;
    }

    public void setActivityName(String activityName) {
        this.activityName = activityName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may get solution by following link:

https://tips.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-showing-push-notification-in-multiline/

http://sudeeprana.com/expand-android-notification-text-to-full-length/

**or**

Android 2.3.3 uses the old notifications without expansion. You must user a shorter text, cut your text (and show the full text when user click on it) or adapt the text if you are showing the notification in Android 4.1 or older.

Expanded notifications are only available from Android 4.1, read here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Answer (score 0):

Convert these:

```
> mBuilder.setStyle(new
> NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageCurr.getMessage()));
>             mBuilder.setContentText("Svolgi al più presto l'attività fisica Pallavvolo ! Clicca su questa notifica per avviare
> l'esercizio..." );
```

to:

```
mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Svolgi al più presto l'attività fisica Pallavvolo ! Clicca su questa notifica per avviare l'esercizio..."));
```

The full text will show when you expand it.

Answer (score 0):

It should work as is. You should "zoom in" your notification by fingers to see all text there.